# passing value through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am new to ajax and i don't have much idea about ajax. I am trying to pass the value from url using ajax but i am not being able to do so. I have done few search on google and found some ajax function code and i tried to implement on my code but one code is not working and another code is giving error. I have left both code below:-

error:-1
ajax code

```
  <script> function loadXMLDoc(loadXMLDoc) { var xmlhttp; if


(window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
 Safari   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();   } else   {
 IE5   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()   {   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4
 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }   } xmlhttp.open("GET","1.php?check=<?php if(isset($_GET['check'])){echo $_GET['check'];}else{echo "i am
 mad";} ?>&name="+loadXMLDoc,true); xmlhttp.send(); } </script>
```

html+php code

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['check'])){echo $_GET['check'];} ?> <?php
 if(isset($_GET['name'])){echo $_GET['name'];} ?> <div id="myDiv"><h2
 style="display:none;">Let AJAX change this text</h2></div> <input
 type="text" onChange="loadXMLDoc(this.value)">
```

error:- 2
ajax code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#delete-btn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "1.php",  
            data: {id: 1234 } 

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

html+php code:

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['id'])){echo $_GET['id'];} ?> `<div id="myDiv"><h2 style="display:none;">Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>`

 <input type="text" onChange="loadXMLDoc(this.value)">
```

I just want to pass the value from url to the same page using ajax but i am not being able to do so. Hope i will get help over here. Thank You in advance.

Comment: what you want to do actually using ajax?

Comment: for passing value from url to same page why did you use ajax?

Comment: @Khushboo I actually want to pass the value through ajax so that page won't reload. I am using javascript to pass the value but their is page reloading problem so i want to use ajax to pass it.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I want to use ajax so that the page won't reload. I know it from javascript but their is page reloading problem. Is their any other way so that page won't reload if yes than please share.

Comment: you want to delete the record from database using ajax, without reload ?

Comment: @Khushboo No i want to send the value to like price(2$,3$), number of order(1,2) from url using ajax and i want to show output of total price by getting value from url(order*price=totalprice)

Comment: Can you indent the code samples you've posted?  It looks like in sample 1, the browser names (like "Safari") are loose in the code.  That would definitely cause an error.  If they are intended to be comments, can you comment them out here so that it appears like the code in your app?

Answer (score 0):

well, the data is passed as the body of the request. 
Set your Content-type in your header request to application/x-www-form-urlencoded so that PHP can $_GET[] it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are asking to pass value into databse

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


 <form>
  enter digit : <input  type="text" id="id" name="id"  /> <br />
    <input type='button' onclick='showUser(this.value)' value='select'/>


   
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

<script>
function showUser() {
                  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
 var id =  document.getElementById("id").value;
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
 
    httpRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost/cart/guser.php?id="+id+"&rand="+true);
    httpRequest.send();
 
  }
  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
       document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
                                 }
 }    
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;    
     
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>

as this progrm is to show the details of the user but there is error in the code in passing the value
```